# Dynamic Django model Table x doesn't exist

Tags: django, csv, dynamic

I'm new to Django and I start to do a project that consist of create a dynamic table based on csv file. The program have to manage columns addition and deletion on the fly.

I face an issue which is that the table do not exist and I don't understand why ... I guess it's a basic problem.
(1146, "Table x doesn't exist")

CSV File is loaded :
python / views.py

```
def gestionTable(request) :
     if (request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']) :
                if (handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], request.POST['table'])) :
                    messages.success(request, 'ok')
                else :
                    messages.error(request, _("failed"))
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('#')
        return render(request, 'weather/gestion_table.html')
```

Model is created here :
Python

```
def csv_to_model(f, tableName):
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    data_list = list(reader)
    col_names = data_list[0]
    first_values = data_list[1]
    fields = {}
    for i in range(len(col_names)) :
        try :
            fields[col_names[i]] =  typeDeduce(type(literal_eval(first_values[i])).__name__)
            print(typeDeduce(type(literal_eval(first_values[i])).__name__))
        except ValueError:
            fields[col_names[i]] =  typeDeduce("str")
    return create_model(name=str(tableName), fields=fields, app_label="weather", module="weather")

def typeDeduce(a):
    if (a == "int") :
        return models.IntegerField()
    if (a == "float") :
        return models.FloatField()
    if (a == "str") : 
        return models.CharField()
```

Dynamic model factory :
Python

```
def create_model(name, fields=None, app_label='', module='', options=None, admin_opts=None):
    class Meta:
        pass

    if app_label:
        setattr(Meta, 'app_label', app_label)

    if options is not None:
        for key, value in options.iteritems():
            setattr(Meta, key, value)

    attrs = {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta}

    if fields:
        attrs.update(fields)

    model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)

  if admin_opts is not None:
        class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            pass
        for key, value in admin_opts:
            setattr(Admin, key, value)
        admin.site.register(model, Admin)

    return model
```

Fulfilling the table :
Python

```
def fulfillTable(f, model, tableName):
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    data_list = list(reader)
    col_names = data_list[0]
    fieldsList = model._meta.get_fields()

    print(fieldsList)
    values = {}
    for row in data_list[1:] :
        for i in range(len(col_names)) :
            try :
                values[col_names[i]] = literal_eval(row[i])
            except ValueError :
                values[col_names[i]] =  row[i]

        model.objects.update_or_create(values) ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a model. Normally, you would need to run `manage.py makemigrations && manage.py migrate` after it.

But since you have a model factory, you have a problem.

If you don't plan to use Django ORM to manipulate data in dynamically created models, your best option is to use [raw sql queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/).

If you do plan to use Django ORM for these models... well you are probably screwed. Some ideas:

If you have your models ready on launching the app, you could try manipulating your models from your [AppConfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/)`.ready`

---

If models are not known/ready on launching your app, you can try your luck with something like the code below.

*Disclaimer: I have no slightest idea whether it has even a chance to work.*

```
from django.core import management
from myapp import models

setattr(models, dynamic_model_name, model)

management.call_command("makemigrations", ["yourappname"])
management.call_command("migrate", ["yourappname"])
```

---

If anything works, or you find a nice answer yourself, please share the result. I'm really curious about this :)

Comment: Thanks, let's give a try !  How do I know  that my model is ready ? ^^'

Comment: @Madostrich By "ready" I meant already exists, created by your factory. If it exists before `AppConfig.ready()`, well probably it does not since I see that `request` argument...

Comment: yep it does not. I tried management.call_command("makemigrations", ["yourappname"])  management.call_command("migrate", ["yourappname"]), it seems like my server do not appreciate that ...

Answer (score 0):

A solution is [schema_editor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/schema-editor/):

```
from django.db import connection, migrations, models

with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor:
        schema_editor.create_model(model)
```